# JavaFX convert WritableImage to Image

Tags: image, javafx, itext

I am doing some application which makes a screenshot of `LineChart` and save it to **pdf** file. So I don't know a smooth way to convert `WritableImage` (JavaFX 2.2) to `Image` (iText lib).

My temporary solution is:

1. to make a snapshot, then
2. get the `WritableImage` from the snapshot
3. write the image to a png file
4. open the image and make iText object `Image`

I would like to make some changes: I don't want to write the `png` file to disc, I just want the snapshot to be written to a pdf file.

My temporary solution is:

```
 WritableImage wim = new WritableImage((int) lineChart.getWidth(),(int) lineChart.getHeight());
 Scene scena = primaryStage.getScene();
 scena.snapshot(wim);
 
 File fileA = new File("C://Graphs/chart.png");
 try {
      ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(wim, null), "png", fileA);
 }
 catch (Exception s) {
 }
 pdfDocument.add(preface3);
 com.itextpdf.text.Image graph =com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance("C://Graphs/chart.png");
 pdfDocument.add((com.itextpdf.text.Element) graph);
```

Comment: I have to do the same thing, I have doing a stuff just like you cause I don't find a better solution for the moment =/

Comment: Like I said this is just my temporary solutin, becaus I need this si I can go to next task..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream  byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ImageIO.write( SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage( wim, null ), "png", byteOutput );

com.itextpdf.text.Image  graph;
graph = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance( byteOutput.toByteArray() );
```

Comment: Thanky you, I would give you a wote but I can't casue I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 0):

My task was to copy drawing from Canvas, it will copy to WritableImage, than get Image from WritableImage (for me it was coping to Clipboard). This Image you can process as you want.

```
        WritableImage wi = new WritableImage((int)gc.getCanvas().getWidth(), 
                (int)gc.getCanvas().getHeight());
        gc.getCanvas().snapshot(null, wi); //Coping all that now in Canvas
        //gc is GraphicContext object from Canvas, it has drawing functions
        BufferedImage bi =SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage((Image)wi, null); 
        SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, (WritableImage)image);
```

Comment: Forgot, "image" is your Image object

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.image.Image cannot be cast to javafx.scene.image.WritableImage